# Custom Notification View in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, custom-notification

I'm trying to find a way to show a custom notification view while app isn't running or device is locked. Is it possible to show custom notification alert for both android and iOS using Appcelerator Titanium ? I'm sharing a image that i want to show as notification message for the user when app is in background or locked mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Such a window is not possible with a local notification that are triggered by the system itself. On Android you have some possibilities to change a notification e.g. like this:

[image: notification]

but the image you are showing is more like an `AlertDialog` is showing inside the app.

To trigger a notification reminder you can have a look at https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager (Android). Still this will trigger a normal system notification.